# Дополнительные методы при переборе массивов через foreach, реализация \Iterator, \ArrayAccess

Tags: php

Реализовал два интерфейса `\Iterator` и `\ArrayAccess` и добавил несколько своих методов, для того, чтобы при переборе массивов, была быстрая возможность, определить, является ли текущая итерация - первой, последней, четной и т.д.

```
class IteratorWrap implements \Iterator, \ArrayAccess {

    private $position = 1;
    private $itemsCount = 0;
    private $array = [];
    private $container = array();

    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->array = $this->container = $array;
        $this->itemsCount = count($array);
    }

    # ArrayAccess interface

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

    # Iterator interface

    public function rewind() : void {
        $this->position = 1;
        reset($this->array);
    }

    public function current() {
        return current($this->array);
    }

    public function key() {
        return key($this->array);
    }

    public function next() : void {
        $this->position++;
        next($this->array);
    }

    public function valid() : bool {
        return isset($this->array[$this->key()]);
    }

    # Extended methods

    public function isFirst() : bool {
        return $this->position == 1;
    }

    public function isLast() : bool {
        return $this->position == $this->count();
    }

    public function isPenult() : bool {
        return $this->count() > 1 && $this->position == $this->count() - 1;
    }

    public function isOdd() : bool {
        return $this->position & 1;
    }

    public function isEven() : bool {
        return !$this->odd(); 
    }

    public function isLt(int $nmb) : bool {
        return $this->position < $nmb;
    }

    public function isGt(int $nmb) : bool {
        return $this->position > $nmb;
    }

    public function count() : int {
        return $this->itemsCount;
    }

}
```

Сейчас это работает так:

```
$arrayIterator = new IteratorWrap($array);
foreach($arrayIterator as $item) {
    if($arrayIterator->isFirst()) { ... }
}
```

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы вложенные массивы, тоже были объектом `IteratorWrap` ?

Чтобы вот так не писать каждый раз:

```
$arrayIterator = new IteratorWrap($array);
foreach($arrayIterator as $item) {
    if(is_array($item)) {
        $innerItem = new IteratorWrap($item);
        ...
    }
}
```

Возможно, надо как-то реализовать интерфейс `IteratorAggregate` ?

Comment: Сунуть проверку на вложенный элемент внутрь класса и возвращать наружу итератор?

Comment: А ещё в SPL среди итераторов есть специальный для массивов https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayiterator.php и на другие там рядом в этом разделе обратите внимание.